# Apache ACE - Simple folder based deployment / provisioning?

Tags: provisioning, apache-ace

I have many bundles (let's say hundreds) and it is quite difficult to specify relation between  bundles+features-distrubutions in UI. Image, at first I define all relations between bundles, features and distribution. Than I want to update some bundles... it is almost impossible to find them in current implementation of UI. They are not groupped and one list of all bundles without any search bar is really hard to work with.

Is there any support for a file based solution. For example Apache ACE would watch a certain folder containing distribnution's bundles. When ever I make a change there, it would be propagate it to all targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no file based solution that matches what you describe, however, I think there are still a couple of solutions that might help you:

1. There are two types of associations between artifacts and features in ACE: static and dynamic ones. The latter can be of help to you, as they always automatically bind to the highest version of a bundle. So, once you've made all your associations, you can simply upload a set of newer bundles and the associations will adapt.
2. There is also a REST API you can use to programmatically talk to ACE. You can use that to further automate your process.

That said, you have a valid point that it is difficult to keep an overview when there are a lot of artifacts in the first column. I would advise you to watch, or even contribute to the following issues that were all created to improve this situation:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACE-319
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACE-320
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACE-321